# nuxt navbar drop downs don't drop

Tags: nuxt.js

I have just started using nuxt and are attempting to get a nav bar working, I have this:

**components/NavBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark">
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Home</b-nav-item>

        <!-- Navbar dropdowns -->
        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="User" right>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar />
    <nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NavBar from "~/components/NavBar.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      NavBar
    }
  };
</script>
```

The navbar renders OK, but the drop-downs don't work - what am I missing ??

## EDIT

Just noticed that it can't find runtime.js - not sure if that's related ?

```
GET _nuxt/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: try to replace `<nav-bar/>` with `<NavBar/>`

Comment: Thanks for helping, just tried and it appears to make no difference, have updated the original post also.

Answer (score 0):

in `pages/index.vue` you shouldn't have  `<nuxt/>` and `<div id="app">` because this tags goes to your `layout/default` file

also remove `.vue` from your `import`

the final code should be like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NavBar />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NavBar from "~/components/NavBar";

  export default {
    components: {
      NavBar
    }
  };
</script>
```

hope it works!